How can I configure OpenIdDict for local token validation?
I use the library OpenIDDict (version 5.*) to work with the token. I have an authorization server that works with tokens. And there is also another regular service, now it works as a client. Sends a request to the authorization service for verification.
My goal is to make the service validate tokens locally and not make a request to another authorization service.
I want to achieve this using certificates. The authorization server and the client have the same certificates.
Server which generates user token
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
            .UseDbContext<ApplicationIdentityDbContext>();
        options.UseQuartz();
    })
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
            .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
            .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
            .SetIntrospectionEndpointUris("/connect/introspect")
            .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");
        options.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Phone, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);
                options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow().AllowCustomFlow("verification_token");
                var encryptionCert = new X509Certificate2("encryption.pfx", "");
        var signingCert = new X509Certificate2("signing.pfx", "");
        options.AddEncryptionCertificate(encryptionCert).AddSigningCertificate(signingCert);
                options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
              options.UseReferenceAccessTokens().UseReferenceRefreshTokens();
        options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(3));
        options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
        options.UseAspNetCore()
            .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration();
    })
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });

Client which should validate this token locally
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.SetIssuer(authority.Address);
        options.AddEncryptionCertificate(LoadCertificateFromFile("encryption.pfx"));
        options.AddSigningCertificate(LoadCertificateFromFile("signing.pfx"));                
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
services.AddAuthorization();


private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificateFromFile(string path)
{
    return new X509Certificate2(path, "");
}

Now if I run the application and try to pass it a Bearer token, it will respond with 401
What am I missing? Please help 
I expect that the token generated by another service (server) will be working in the service (client) where the certificate check is performed locally. The goal is to get rid of requests to the authorization service
